# Htaccess issue with subfolder and with languange

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdirectory

I have a core PHP website that is hosted over a server and now I have moved the website to a subfolder to access the website something like that example.com/site. that website also use the .htaccess for managing multiple language.but after moving it to subfolder website is not accessible. Please see the following .htaccess file. This .htaccess is when the website is on root folder I want this .htacess to work when on subfolder /site/ please help me.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)   https://www.example.com/$1  [L,R=301]

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # URL rewriting module activation
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 

    RewriteRule ^en/([^?&]*)$ /$1?lang=en [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/privacy-policy$ /privacy-policy.php?lang=en [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/legal-notice$ /legal-notice.php?lang=fr [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^fr/politique-de-confidentialite$ /privacy-policy.php?lang=fr [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/mentions-legales$ /legal-notice.php?lang=fr [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/([^?&]*)$ /$1?lang=fr [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try these rules in `/site/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# add www and turn on https in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^en/privacy-policy/?$ privacy-policy.php?lang=en [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^en/legal-notice/?$ legal-notice.php?lang=fr [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^fr/politique-de-confidentialite/?$ privacy-policy.php?lang=fr [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^fr/mentions-legales/?$ legal-notice.php?lang=fr [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(en|fr)/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Ah, there was a typo error. Fixed now. Can you try updated answer.

Comment: @anubhava, Hello sir, so it means either user can create a new .htaccess in site directory OR move current folder .htaccess file to site directory that should be same thin,correct? Also 2nd thought on this one(sorry I am new on this one :) ): Can we use existing path's .htaccess file and could change path values in it sir?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: OP wanted `I want this .htacess to work when on subfolder /site/ ` that is why this I answered this .htaccess to work in `/site/` subdirectory. User has to create a new .htaccess inside `/site/` for this leaving root one as is (if present).

Comment: @anubhava, sure thank you sir for guiding here, thanks a TON:)

Answer (score 0):

You can add 
`RewriteBase /site/`
then write the conditions like

```
RewriteRule ^site/en/privacy-policy/?$ site/privacy-policy.php?lang=en [QSA,L]
```

Comment: it's not working tried this https://prnt.sc/sfjd1e and https://prnt.sc/sfjdhh

Comment: Did you change  `RewriteRule ^(.*)   https://www.example.com/$1  [L,R=301] `accordingly.
Like `RewriteRule ^(.*)   https://www.example.com/site/$1  [L,R=301]`